# Creating a 360-Degree Hover Rotation Effect on a Gradient Button in CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

I Have this button in my homepage[[Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcQ6W.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcQ6W.png). When I hover over the button I want the gradient to rotate 360 degrees perpetually. But I don't now how to do this at my current level of scss. Its for my homepage. I want add the button as another style to make the homepage popout more.

my jsx:

```
<section className='section-cover'>
        <div className='cover-title'>
          <h1>Blah Blah, Blah Blah </h1>
          <h2>You never have to do it yourself again, Blah Blah Blah Blah and let someone do the work for you.</h2>
          <button className='try-out'>Try Us Out</button>
        </div>
        <img className='cuttingBlah' src={cuttingBlah}/>
</section>
```

my scss:

```
.section-cover {
    margin-top: 60px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 50px 100px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    ::before, ::after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        inset: 0;
        background: linear-gradient(
            0deg,
            var(--color-2),
            var(--color-3),
            var(--color-4),
            var(--color-5),
            var(--color-6),
        );
        z-index: -1;
    }
    ::before {
        filter: blur(0.5rem);
    }
    .cover-title {
        z-index: 2;
        h1, h2 {
            color: black;
            margin: 0px;
        }
        h1 {
            font-size: 55px;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
        }
        .try-out {
            box-sizing: content-box;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: large;
            padding: 1rem 2rem;
            cursor: pointer;
            position: relative;
            border: 10px solid transparent;
            background: linear-gradient(white, white) padding-box,
                        linear-gradient( to right, #5ddcff, #3c67e3 43%, #4e00c2) border-box;
            border-radius: 20px;
            margin-top: 20px;
            overflow: hidden; 
            transition: transform 0.5s ease; 
        }
    }
    .cuttingBlah {
        border-radius: 10px;
        width: 520px;
        z-index: 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: "When I click hover over the button" – could you clarify what you mean by "click hover" please?

Comment: @Wongjn, I meant 'hover', not 'click hover'.